# How to convert mongoose query in string format to actual query object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on application and sending multiple query strings to the server and based on that query strings parameters I'm going to create a mongodb query object as a string dynamically and then when I got a complete query in string format I want to pass it to the find method and based on that query the results will be retrieved from the database.
Let have a look at demo code:

```
// This would be the query that will be generated dynamically.
{ fullName: "Rehan Shah", PhoneNumber: "+92 315 1234567", Package: "'5df6339e5c2c9108a8d57ef0"}

// Would be stored in the variable.
let query_parameters = "{ fullName: "Rehan Shah", PhoneNumber: "+92 315 1234567", Package: "'5df6339e5c2c9108a8d57ef0"}";
```

Now I want to pass query parameter to the find method.

```
Model.find(query_parameters).then().catch();
```

But with this implementation the query parameters is actually a string not a actual query object. How to convert it to the actual object? I researched alot but can't find any solution yet.

How to solve this issue? Help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert json object using JSON.parse()

```
let query_parameters = "{ fullName: "Rehan Shah", PhoneNumber: "+92 315 1234567", Package: "'5df6339e5c2c9108a8d57ef0"}";

Model.find(JSON.parse(query_parameters)).then().catch();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to pass object as a string

Simply store the object to a variable

```
// eg object
var user = { fullName: "Rehan Shah", PhoneNumber: "+92 315 1234567", Package: "'5df6339e5c2c9108a8d57ef0" }
```

then either you can pass the object directly to the query

```
let query_parameters = user;
```

or you can also call it independently as per your convenience

```
let query_parameters = {
    fullName: user.fullName,
    PhoneNumber: user.PhoneNumber,
    Package: user.Package
};
```

Then you can finally fire your query

```
Model.find(query_parameters).then().catch();
```

If you want to add projection to your query

```
let projection = {
    $sort: {
        fullName: 1
    }
};

Model.find(query_parameters, projection).then().catch();
```